# Rails: Find entity by many-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, many-to-many, associations

I have a model A, and a model B. A `has_and_belongs_to_many` Bs, and vice versa.

Now, I want to find an object/entity within A that has_and_belongs_to certain objects within B (say B1 and B2). How can I do that *efficiently* within Rails? My current solution is something like this:

```
A.all.select {|a| a.bs.sort == [B1, B2]}.first
```

It basically iterates through *all* objects within A and checks if it `has_and_belongs_to` the correct Bs. That is very inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does the `A` you're looking for have to be in a relationship with `B1`, `B2` and _no_ other `B`'s, or is `A` allowed to be in a relationship with other `B`'s, say `B3` and `B4`? I ask because in your block, you're testing for _equality_ (`a.bs.sort == [B1, B2]`) rather than _inclusion_ (`(a.bs - [B1, B2]).empty?`).

Comment: Yes, _equality_ is what I am looking for, not just mere inclusion. It has to be in relationship with both B1 _and_ B2, and with no other B's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with nested sub-queries, which is a working solution but not necessarily an *efficient* one, so you'll have to run some benchmarks.

The following involves three nested queries performed on the join_table between `A` and `B`.
You first determine the id's of all `B`'s (call these `excluded_bs`) that are not either `B1` or `B2`. Then, you determine which `A`'s are in a relationship with these `excluded_bs` and call them `excluded_as`. All the `A`'s that are not in `excluded_as` are exactly the ones we want (call them `included_as`). Once you have `included_as` just query the `A` table.

```
excluded_bs = %(SELECT B_id FROM join_table WHERE B_id NOT IN (:included_bs))
excluded_as = %(SELECT A_id FROM join_table WHERE B_id IN (#{excluded_bs}))
included_as = %(SELECT A_id FROM join_table WHERE A_id NOT IN (#{excluded_as}))

A.where("id IN (included_as)", :included_bs => [B1.id, B2.id])
```

This should give you all the `A`'s that are in a relationship with exactly `B1` and `B2`, but not with any others. You might be able to clean this up a bit and make it more efficient, but it should at least work.

EDIT:

Whoops! To trim off those that only have either `B1` or `B2`, try a `GROUP BY`. Change the last sub-query to

```
included_as = %(SELECT A_id, COUNT(*) as Total FROM join_table WHERE A_id NOT IN (#{excluded_as}) GROUP BY A_id HAVING Total = :count)
```

and the main query to

```
Bs = [B1, B2]
A.where("id IN (SELECT A_id FROM (#{included_as}))", :included_bs => Bs.map(&:id), :count => Bs.count)
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't run this yet (will do now), but it seems to me like that doesn't guarantee that included_as actually includes B1 and B2, just that they don't include anything else. Not sure, though, will think about it more and give it a try.

Comment: Yea, I tried it and as I thought, it returns As that just have B1 in there, or just B2 (or both), instead of only the one that has both B1 and B2.

Comment: @user1013725 Sorry, I overlooked that. I haven't had a chance to try the edit, but see if that works.

Comment: Hmm, it tells me "no such column: COUNT". I guess this is a syntax issue? EDIT: Changing it to "HAVING COUNT(b_id) = :count" seems to make it work. I am still trying to test all the edge cases, but it's looking good...

Comment: I realized that right before you posted. Try the second modification above. Your edit should work just as well, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter on habtm associations:

```
A.joins(:bs).where("bs.id" => [B1, B2]).first

A.joins(:bs).where("bs.id" => [B1, B2]).all
```

To ensure that only the items with exactly two associations are returned, use

```
A.joins(:bs).where("bs.id" => [B1, B2]).group("as.id HAVING COUNT(bs.id) = 2")
```

Comment: Again, this doesn't test for equality, but just for inclusion, right? In other words, this can return a model that has_and_belongs_to B1, but not to B2.

Comment: Now I read your comment in the original question. You have to use group by + having (like in plain SQL). See further edit.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that last edit statement still returns more than one result.

Comment: that's because I didn't add the "first" final clause, so you can chain whatever additional condition.

Comment: Well, I only have one A that has_and_belongs_to B1 and B2. So I am trying to find that one A. There are no further conditions, just that equality condition. The final statement returns several As, one of which is the one I am looking for, but also some other As that have different Bs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17779/discussion-between-saverio-and-user1013725)